# How can I change the background color of blur view while using peek and pop in swift 2.0 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch, uiblureffect

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

     //Getting someId using the location and then I just create a view controller depending onthat id
     return viewControllerForPlayer(someId) //This returns the view controller I am trying to peek
}
```

Blur view has a white background color which is different from other parts of the app.
Question: what decides the blur background color while peek and pop and how can I change it

Comment: What do you mean by "peek and pop"?

Comment: Peek and Pop is this new 3D Touch feature from iPhone 6s onwards, where users can quickly peek into the content by pressing hard and pop it if they like like.

Comment: any news on this case?

Comment: @DavidSeek nah, still couldn't find it.

Answer (score -1):

According to brief Google research there are couple tweaks for iPhones that change blur color of the applications to correspond their icon tint color, but all of them are for Jailbreak devices. So it looks like there is no declared possibility to change force touch blur color right now.

Comment: any news on this case?